# Twilio fax - How to manage status responses in Wordpress in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, twilio, twilio-php, fax

I want to send and manage faxes using PHP only (no JavaScript or cron, if possible) through [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) from my linux+Apache+Wordpress site. (Development is on a Wordpress site through my localhost using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).)

I have been able to set up a Wordpress page ([template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/)) to send faxes using [Twilio's fax API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/fax). After the fax is sent, though, Twilio is replying with [JSON in a POST response](https://www.twilio.com/docs/fax/send#fax-status-callbacks) (I think), and expecting my site to respond in some way. I have a callback URL in place, but this seems to be an asynchronous call, which I don't know how to handle though Wordpress. (I want to stay within Wordpress site if possible for security and convenience.)

I have no experience with managing this type of communication between servers; I have been reading the Twilio docs, but I think I am making a fundamental mistake somewhere...I get the gist of *what* needs to be done, but not *how* it works.

How does managing Twilio's asynchronous calls work using PHP within Wordpress?

Comment: Maybe this site has a workable approach: "Saving the post, sending data to the remote API, and recording the result as post meta does not have to be one discrete process." https://torquemag.io/2016/01/use-asynchronous-php-wordpress/

Answer (score 2):

Twilio can be set up to use the REST API standard. (Wordpress has a tutorial for [setting up REST routes and endpoints](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/).)

Create a custom Twilio endpoint on Wordpress using `register_rest_route`. This can be set up as POST or GET, but it has to match [your Twilio fax number](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming) settings.

For example, put the following in your theme's `functions.php` file (you should [create a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) before doing this if you haven't already):

```
function process_twilio_fax_response( $request ) {
  $params = $request->get_params();
  // $params should have the data Twilio POSTed as JSON to the API.
  // For example, $params['account_sid'] should have the account_sid.
}

// This code registers the API endpoint and tells wordpress to call process_twilio_fax_response
// when data is POSTed to /wp-json/twilio/callback 
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'twilio', '/callback', array(
    // WP_REST_Server:READABLE = GET only
    // WP_REST_Server:CREATABLE = POST only
    // WP_REST_Server:EDITABLE = POST, PUT, PATCH
    // WP_REST_Server:DELETABLE = DELETE only
    // WP_REST_Server:ALLMETHODS = GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
    'methods' => WP_REST_Server:CREATABLE,
    'callback' => 'process_twilio_fax_response',
  ) );
} );
```

This will create an endpoint at /wp-json/twilio/callback (e.g. `https://www.example.com/wp-json/twilio/callback`) which can be configured on [your Twilio fax number](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming) as the **"A Fax Comes In"** URL (or "Fax Status Changes", or "Primary Handler Fails").

When Twilio makes a POST request to the endpoint, the callback function (in this case `process_twilio_fax_response`) will be called with the request object passed as a parameter. You can then get the JSON data as an associative array by calling `get_params()` method on the parameter (in this case `$request->get_params()`).

Please be aware that this example has no authentication, sanitation, or validation, all of which are necessary for any public-facing REST route.

---

If you are debugging on `localhost`, the callback URL will be `http://localhost/wp-json/twilio/callback`. Twilio won't be able to POST to `localhost` since it is accessible only locally, but you can set up a web tunnel through a random, temporary URL on linux using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). In [your Twilio fax number](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming) setup, change any reference to `localhost` domain with the ngrok domain, keeping all other URL resources, queries, etc. the same. E.g.:

```
https://localhost/SomeWordpressDomainName/wp-json/twilio/callback
```

becomes

```
https://randomDomainNameFromNGROK.ngrok.io/SomeWordpressDomainName/wp-json/twilio/callback
```

Comment: Looks promising. I'll try the suggestion soon. (For localhost, https://ngrok.com creates a random, temporary website where Twilio can transparently communicate with my local site.)

Comment: Still exploring whether this works in practice. I am reading the relevant docs about Wordpress' [register_rest_route](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/) including the docs at [REST API Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/), specifically [Extending the REST API / Routes and Endpoints](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/).